# jQuery droppable not firing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm prototyping a drag and drop example below which is doing everything I ask except that I cannot get the drop event to fire.

The elements just revert without pasting into the content div. Any ideas what I'm missing

```
    <ul class="keywords">
        <li class="draggable" id="kw-1">keyword one</li>
        <li class="draggable" id="kw-2">keyword two</li>
        <li class="draggable" id="kw-3">keyword three</li>
    </ul>


    <div id='editorcontainer'>
        <textarea rows='10' class='theEditor' cols='40' name='content' id='content'>drop content here</textarea>
    </div>


    jQuery(".myDiv").find("li").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).draggable(
    { 
        revert:true, 
        helper:'clone', 

        start: function(event, ui) {
            jQuery(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
            }, 

        stop: function(event, ui) { 
            jQuery(this).fadeTo(0, 1); 
            } 
    });});

    jQuery('#content').droppable({ 
        drop: function(event, ui) { 
            alert('dropped') //DOES NOT FIRE!
            //drop text into content editor
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `revert:true` option, which is reverting every single drop before the `drop` event on the `droppable` fires. Replace this:

```
jQuery(this).draggable(
{ 
    revert:true, // <-- Revert every single drop
    helper:'clone', 

    start: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        }, 

    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        jQuery(this).fadeTo(0, 1); 
        } 
});
```

With this:

```
jQuery(this).draggable({
        revert: 'invalid', // <-- Revert invalid drops
        helper: 'clone',

        start: function(event, ui) {
            jQuery(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },

        stop: function(event, ui) {
            jQuery(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7t56R/

Comment: + 1 and done, but apparently all of my drops are invalid. I'm still not getting alert on drops and the revert is triggered on every attempted drop.

Comment: In my code. The droppable is the WordPress content editor. Any ideas why it would not accept the drop? Perhaps its already binding to a droppable thats clashing with mine?

Comment: @Scott: Interesting. Removing the `revert` option all together is probably worth at try just to see what happens.

Comment: Yep, did that. I think you've answered my question. This is apparently a WP specific issue with drag and drop, no?

Comment: @Scott: I'm not sure actually... I am not too familiar with WP so I can't say for sure `:(`